# why does the errror "permission denied", "id returned 1 exit status" come only when im using the header file fstream in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I cant seem to use the header file **fstream**

I've tried downloading the header file and linking it to the compiler but it still shows the same error.

```
ofstream file("file.txt",ios::out);
    file<<"text file.";
```

the text is supposed to be copied to the file, but when I run it, the file isn't created and the output screen terminates without displaying anything.
These are the errors:

```
cannot open output file, Permission denied
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is generated by `ld`, your linker. It says it cannot open the output file (the executable you're trying to create).

**This is probably because *you're already running your program* somewhere.**

Close it, so that your compiler & linker can replace it with the new version you're trying to build.

---

Copy/pasting the contents of your toolchain's fstream header won't change anything; it's more likely to break things.

In fact, this has nothing to do with `fstream`, or with header files, or anything like that. I suspect that you added some `fstream` functionality and then the next rebuild (intended to test the new code) triggered the problem.

You can verify this by now *removing* your new `fstream` code and noting that the problem does not go away. Always try to narrow down your problems by a process of trial, error and verification.